# Excel VBA: end user select image on computer and submit on user form

Tags: image, excel, vba

I have a userform with a bunch of textboxes. End user inputs test data into form and after clicking "Submit" button, this info is saved to an excel sheet. I am wondering how to make it possible for user to input images from their computer into the form.

Requirements: End user be able to select an image from their computer and click submit on the form to have it inserted into an excel sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim image As FileDialog 
    Set image = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 
    Dim vrtSelectedPicture As Variant 
    With image 
        If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each vrtSelectedPicture In .SelectedItems                 
            'Show path in textbox
            TextBox71.Text = .SelectedItems(1)      
        Next vrtSelectedPicture
        'The user pressed Cancel.
        Else
        End If
    End With
    'Set the object variable to Nothing
    Set image = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just record the path to the image and then insert it upon submit?

Comment: Like recording the file path? Would such a method allow for a non-tech savvy person using the form to upload images? New pictures are taken on the spot per form

Comment: I guess when you say "upload" and "corresponding cells" it doesn't make much sense to me since you don't explain how you will know what cells are supposed to go with the image, if you need a variable amount of images, what you want the end user to do in order to get the images into the form, how you want it to look, etc.. tons of information is missing from your post. The basic idea of having the user browse for an image on their computer, select it, and click submit and have it inserted into an excel sheet can be a very easy task but you leave out so much information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to VBA and am still learning the ropes >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, here is a sample code that may give you an idea about `FileDialog`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Add "Image", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ' file has been selected

            ' e.g. show path in textbox
            Me.TextBox1.Text = .SelectedItems(1)

            ' e.g. display preview image in an image control
            Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            ' user aborted the dialog

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here! I altered it a bit and it worked! In order to add more than one image, would there need to be a for loop somewhere in the code? Ohh duh nvm you had it in the filter